# loading empty window javafx

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder

when i run this code it supposed to open a new window with the fxml loaded but it just opens a window that is empty.

CODE for Startup:

```
public class StartUpGui extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    DomeinController dc = new DomeinController();
    UC1Controller root = new UC1Controller(dc);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Mastermind");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

CODE for first screen(this works)

```
public class UC1Controller extends AnchorPane {
 public UC1Controller(DomeinController dc) {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("UC1.fxml"));
    loader.setRoot(this);
    loader.setController(this);
    this.dc = dc;

    try {
        loader.load();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UC1Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

@FXML
private void startAnderUC(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getTarget() == btn_UC2) {
        startUsecase2();
    }

}


public void startUsecase2() {


    UC2Controller UC2 = new UC2Controller(dc);
    Scene scene = new Scene(UC2);
    Stage stage = new  Stage();
    stage.setTitle("Mastermind");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
}
```

Code second Screen (doesnt work)

```
public class UC2Controller extends AnchorPane {

public UC2Controller(DomeinController dc) {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("UC2.fxml"));
    loader.setController(this);
    this.dc =dc;

    try {
        loader.load();



    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UC1Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

}
```

so when i load the first one it goes as it should but when i click on the button to start useCase2 it doesnt show errors just doesnt load a new screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `UC2Controller` you simply drop the loaded result without adding it to a scene. `FXMLLoader` doesn't add it either, since you don't set the `root` before loading the fxml.

You need to set the root in `UC2Controller`:

```
public UC2Controller(DomeinController dc) {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("UC2.fxml"));
    loader.setController(this);
    loader.setRoot(this);
    this.dc = dc;
    try {
        loader.load();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex); // cannot recover from this -> rethrow exception
    }

}
```

Alternatively you could manually add the loaded nodes to the scene:

```
public UC2Controller(DomeinController dc) {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("UC2.fxml"));
    loader.setController(this);
    this.dc = dc;
    try {
        this.getChildren().add(loader.load());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex); // cannot recover from this -> rethrow exception
    }

}
```

The first alternative requires `<fx:root>` to be the root element of `UC2.fxml`:

```xml
<fx:root xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane">
    ...
</fx:root>
```